# Point Cloud Filtering and processing using PCL is slow

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All

I have code for a ROS node that subscribes to A PointCloud2 topic published by iai_kinect2's kinect bridge. My problem is that the code runs quite slowly. I have narrowed down the slowing-down to my spinOnce() statement, so I'm pretty sure it's my callback function that's being slow. However, my callback is using the reccommended way of converting the pc2 message into a PCL point cloud. Here it is for reference:

```
void cloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg){
  // Create a container for the data.
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg,pcl_pc2);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*cloud);

  pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud,*outputCloud, indices);

  sor.setInputCloud(outputCloud);
  sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
  sor.filter (*outputCloudFilt);
}
```

All the objects used here were pre-initialised before main(). The code runs just as slowly if I remove the filtering from the callback.

I should also add that the speed is slow independently of how many points are in the cloud.

EDIT: Using fromROSMsg() doesn't help with my problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347392/point-cloud-filtering-and-processing-using-pcl-is-slow/) by [christophecricket](https://answers.ros.org/users/52810/christophecricket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-24**:
Something to check: did you compile with optimisations enabled?

And not an answer, but `pcl_ros` comes with a few PCL filters wrapped in nodelets: [wiki/pcl_ros - Nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#ROS_nodelets).

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-24**:
Also, please give us your full code, for all we know the issue is somewhere over there. Also please describe what "slow" means to you. Give us some metrics to work with.

**Comment by [christophecricket](https://answers.ros.org/users/52810/christophecricket/) on 2020-03-24**:
Yeah fair enough. I meant that my code was running at like 0.1Hz, which is way slower than you would actually expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @gvdhoorn turning on compiler optimisation gives me speeds more in line with what I expect (~20-30Hz, and actually scales with the size of the cloud). To anyone else experiencing this problem: set the following flag in `catkin_make`:

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

---

Originally posted by [christophecricket](https://answers.ros.org/users/52810/christophecricket/) with karma: 21 on 2020-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-24**:
Sounds about right! Was this for setting in your application or in your PCL/PCL ROS build itself?

**Comment by [christophecricket](https://answers.ros.org/users/52810/christophecricket/) on 2020-03-25**:
I just turned it on for the entirety of the packages in my `src/` folder.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-25**:
And what’s in that? PCL, pcl_perception? Just your application code?

**Comment by [christophecricket](https://answers.ros.org/users/52810/christophecricket/) on 2020-03-25**:
Oooh I just got what you're trying to ask. No it's just my application code. I didn't recompile the binaries for PCL or ROS.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-25**:
ah ok,thanks